# Unable to delete a record from self indexed db object

Tags: mysql, database

I am not able to delete a row from a database object.  In my case db object is having self indexing.
A field root_id is having a foreign key relation with key_id (Primary key). The referential integrity is designed as `ON UPDATE NO ACTION AND ON DELETE NO ACTION`.  Even still I am not able to delete.

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_MyTab` FOREIGN KEY (`root_id`) REFERENCES `MyTab` (`key_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I have to delete records from this table `WHERE key_id = root_id`.
When I try to delete I am getting the following.

> Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`MyTab`, CONSTRAINT `fk_MyTab` FOREIGN KEY (`root_id`) REFERENCES `MyTab` (`key_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what `NO ACTION` does, it prevents deletion of a row with any child rows. If you want to delete the children too, use `CASCADE`.

You could also preserve the data by setting it to `ON DELETE SET NULL`, in which case if the parent is deleted the child rows will have their foreign key column set to null.

Comment: Hai @Asad, need one clarification. Is this the bug in MySQL or it is common for all DB servers?

Comment: @vissu This isn't a bug, it is a feature; and a similar one exists for all DB servers. If you want to prevent any row that has child rows from being deleted, you use `NO ACTION`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good practice to do when you're designing a database that has lots of foreign keys. If you have tables with ON DELETE CASCADE option which are linked with other field to other tables, the delete cascade option will fail (because mysql could not delete in the same order you create the tables)". A solution for this case is to declare a clause ON DELETE SET NULL in the others foreign keys

Comment: This is exactly what I posted?

Comment: Not exact. But its also comes to mean the same. Because this the solution.